# Checking if a date has events in yii2fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, yii2, fullcalendar

I'm using [yii2fullcalendar](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2fullcalendar) and trying to check if a clicked date has events. If the date has events, a modal will popup to show the events in it. If it doesn't, a modal will popup to show a form for adding an event into it.

I tried this:

```
function IsDateHasEvent(date) {
    var allEvents = [];
    allEvents = $('#w4').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var event = $.grep(allEvents, function(v) {
        return +v.start === +date;
    });
    return event.length > 0;
}
```

And use it to check the clicked date:

```
function(calEvent) {
var tanggal = calEvent.format(); 
console.log(IsDateHasEvent(tanggal));
if(!IsDateHasEvent(tanggal)){
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    $.get('index', function(data) {
        $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').html(data)
    });
}
else{
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    $.get(base_url+'/pacakplus/dailyreport/input?date='+tanggal, function(data) {
        $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').html(data)
    });
}
$('#w0').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

The results keep returning false no matter which date I click on.

I tried alerting the `IsDateHasEvent` function and it gives me this:

```
localhost says:
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `IsDateHasEvent` returns an array, so checking whether it returns true or false doesn't make much sense. It also returns all the events currently visible in the calendar, which isn't helpful either. It _would_ make more sense though, if you replaced `return allEvents;` with the line just below it which is currently commented out...is there any specific reason you commented that line out? That would return a boolean true/false showing whether any events were found on that date or not.

Comment: P.S. That plugin you're using is based on a very old version of fullCalendar. It would be better to use the latest fullCalendar directly. It's not difficult to integrate that with the server-side code, all you need is an endpoint which returns the event data in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo from when I was trying out my initial code. I tried another way around the issue and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't work it out the way I tried in the question. It seems the extension I used uses the old version of Full Calendar as suggested by ADyson in the comments.
So I tried another way, with this:

```
function(calEvent) {
  var date= calEvent.format();  
  theId = "project-" + date;
  $('.calendar[id*="' + theId + '"]').show();
  $('.calendar[id!="' + theId + '"]').hide();
  $('#clue-calendar').hide();
  return false;    
}
```

The #project div:

```
<?php if ($model->date== date("Y-m-d")) { ?>
    <div id="project-<?php echo $model->when_to?>">
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="project-<?php echo $model->when_to?>" style="display:none">
<?php } ?>

    <div class="info-box">
        <span class="info-box-icon bg-info"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <div class="info-box-content">
            <span class="info-box-number">#<?php echo $model->timkerjaprojecte->project_name ?></span>                
            <span class="info-box-text"><?php echo 'Due On ' . date("d F Y", strtotime($model->when_to)) ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this helps someone.